# Where to import LinBnDrop layer from in Fastai or pyTorch?

Tags: fast-ai

I wonder where to find the `LinBnDrop` layer class in Fastai? The [documentation](https://docs.fast.ai/layers#LinBnDrop) only describes the class, but does not show where to import it from.

Answer (score 2):

And found it:

```
from fastai.layers import LinBnDrop
```